# How do I train Bixby to recognize a wild card search term?

Tags: bixby

I have an action FindPage.js that finds pages and retrieves them for display as results. I understand how to train it to find pages with utterances like "Read the Twitter Search page" or "Read the Searchable Text page".  The training treats "Twitter Search" as SearchTerm and the code below matches SearchTerm to the tag field in the data.  But how would I train to understand a command like "Read all pages"?  I want the code to carry out a search on the wildcard and bring back all available pages.

```
// search for informational pages

var console = require('console');

const PAGES = require('./content/pages')

 pages = PAGES
 console.log('pages are', pages)

exports.function = function findPage (searchTerm) {
  console.log('searchTerm is', searchTerm)
  var matches = []  
  pages = PAGES

  for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    if (searchTerm == pages[i].tag) {
        matches.push(pages[i])
    }
    else

        { console.log('no tag matches')        
          }
    }

  console.log('matches are', matches)
  return matches
}
```

Training:

[g:Page] Read the (Twitter Search)[v:SearchTerm] page.

Answer (score 1):

This works although I feel it is somewhat clunky to hardcode a conversion from "all" to the include wildcard string, which is ''.

```
exports.function = function findPage (searchTerm) {
  //console.log('searchTerm is', searchTerm)

  if (searchTerm == 'all') {
    searchTerm = ''
    console.log('searchTerm is all', searchTerm)
    }
  else
  { console.log('searchTerm is not all', searchTerm)
    }

  var matches = []  
  pages = PAGES



  matches = pages.filter(function(pages) {
  return pages.tag.includes(searchTerm);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Examples See example

```
const str = 'To be, or not to be, that is the question.';
console.log(str.includes('To be'));       // true
console.log(str.includes(''))             // true
```